# cakephp2 validate emails in controller before send multiple message

Tags: email, controller, cakephp-2.3, email-validation

In Cakephp2, i would like to verify emails which stocked from a mysql database before sending an emailing to many participants.

the problem is if the application meet a bad email => it crash.

I've implemented a validate fonction in the Controller but the bad emails are not filtered and the application crash.

How will i do to separate the bad email to the rest to let  the application continue and send all the goods emails without crashing?

eventually , i would keep all emails bad in $erreurs.

Heu....Before posting here, i've read, search and try......

Thanks

## Controller

```
/* $trouve=result of find (all)*/


 $envoyes= 0;
 $non_envoyes = 0;

   foreach ($trouve as $k => $v)
 {               
      if($this>VueAppliMouv>validates(array('fieldList'=>array('email'))))
       {
          /*i do my emailing=> it's working */
         $send++;

         }

       else

           { 
               $erreurs= $this->VueAppliMouv->validationErrors; 
           no_send++;
        }
  }
```

## Model

```
 public $validate = array(
'email'=>   array(
            'rule'=>'email'  ,
            'required'=>false ,
            'allowEmpty'=>false,
            'message'=>"Indiquez un email valide"
        )
 ); //fin validate
```

## View

```
 <h1> il y a eu <?=$envoyes ;?> mails envoyés</h1> <br>
    <h1> il y a eu <?=$non_envoyes ;?> mails  NON envoyés</h1> <br>


<?php
        if (is_array($erreurs))
        {
            foreach ($erreurs as $key => $valeur)
            {
                echo "erreur" . $key . "" . $valeur."\n";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "$erreurs \n";
        }
```

i've send 2 mails:

the first with bad  adress, 
and the second with a good adress.

even the good one  didn't arrive...

## Result

Invalid email: "rvagui@gmail"
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Stack Trace

Comment: Why are you allowing bad emails into your database in the first place? Seems that the time for validation would be when you're writing the records, not when you go to send the emails.

Comment: you're right, but the insertion of emails come from another application(C# , imade from another people, and the validation isn't made.I'm agree with you , it would be easier....

Comment: Unfortunate. :-( I don't see anything in your code that sets the data (i.e. row, with email address) that `$this>VueAppliMouv>validates` will be looking at. I skipped over v2, so I'm not sure what that will be looking at, but it's never going to change as you go through the records, so unsurprising that you're seeing the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: ok, i've selected the essential  code to put only essential and i forgot this line `` $this->VueAppliMouv->set($trouve);``      just before `` foreach ($trouve as $k => $v)``
 {               
      if($this>VueAppliMouv>validates(array('fieldList'=>array('email'))))                                                Thanks Greg for your answer

Comment: If you've put the `set` before the `foreach`, then no wonder that the `validates` call returns the same answer every time through the loop: you're not changing the data it's looking at.